# SharePoint 2010 Search is crawling unpublished items and draft items

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Sharepoint search crawler indexing items that are not published and draft items , I double checked the permissions of the search crawling account and account as only read-only access to the site.

when someone is searching for something all unpublished items and drafts are coming up in search results and we want to avoid it.

and it is a publishing site.
any thoughts?

Comment: Are regular users seeing the unpublished items in search results or just you?  The information in this post may be helpful. They appear to have the opposite issue: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/15576/search-for-unpublished-documents

Comment: its a public facing external site , all the users having the same behavior that is everyone can see the unpublished items in search results.

Comment: Log into SharePoint with the crawl account. If you can see unpublished items change the security until you cannot.

Answer (score 0):

Check the draft item security setting (part of the versioning settings) in your libs, you need to set that only users who can edit items are able to see drafts.